# Android Launch a Google Drive application from another application not uploaded file

Tags: android-intent, google-drive-api

I tried to upload a file from my android application by manually launching Google drive (installed on the device). I tried this to send  using `Intent.createChooser` and its working fine for uploading file attachment. But I need to upload file for specific intent (like Dropbox, Google drive only). So I changed the code and tried to upload a file to Google drive as following ways, but no success, only Google drive app is open on device, no file uploaded:

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs");
intent.setType("application/pdf");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://sdcard/sdcard0/test.pdf"));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "attach a file test");
intent.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
startActivity(intent);
```

Can we upload a PDF file by opening the intent manually as above?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got the solution for executing following code after research:

```
import android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat;

Uri pdfUri = Uri.parse("file://sdcard/sdcard0/test.pdf");                
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
                                     .setText("Share PDF doc")
                                         .setType("application/pdf")
                                         .setStream(pdfUri )
                                         .getIntent()
                                 .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Similarly we can use for other share intent and the corresponding package name of few intents are as below:

- com.dropbox.android = Dropbox
- com.android.bluetooth = Bluetooth
- com.android.email = Email
- com.google.android.gm = Gmail
- com.microsoft.skydrive = Skydrive
- com.google.android.apps.docs = Googledrive

For gmail sharing we need to use following type of code:

```
Uri zipUri = Uri.parse("file://sdcard/sdcard0/test.zip");  
String[] emailArr = {"test@gmail.com"};              
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
                                  .setText("Share ZIP doc")
                                  .setType("application/zip")
                                  .setEmailTo(emailArr)
                                  .setStream(zipUri)
                                  .setSubject("Share zip doc")
                                  .setText("Sent with email app.")
                                  .getIntent()
                           .setPackage("com.google.android.gm");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: getting this error. Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.driveshareintent/com.example.driveshareintent.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=application/pdf flg=0x80001 pkg=com.google.android.apps.docs (has clip) (has extras) }

Comment: @Ravi: You have to have the application installed: so allways check for this exception! (or you used a not existing package name)

Comment: If i can upvote 100 times within an hour i will spend one hour for this answer..... awesome man

Comment: Is it working in marshmallow and plus ? i  am getting security exception can you please help

Comment: I tried it will only work for android 6.0 and above, when you make your own provider.
for others help you can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249007/how-to-use-support-fileprovider-for-sharing-content-to-other-apps/39619468#39619468

Comment: Is it possible to launch into Google Docs to use their scan feature ?