# How can i share my pdf with dropbox and Google drive?

Tags: android, pdf, share, dropbox, google-drive-api

I have create a `pdf` and now want to `upload` it on `Google drive` and `Dropbox` but not able to upload. i have used the following code:

```
    Uri pdfUri = Uri.parse("file://" + File.separator+ "sdcard" + File.separator + "A****" File.separator + "A****.pdf");
    Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(TripHome.this).setText("Share PDF doc").setType("application/pdf").setStream(pdfUri).getIntent().setPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs");
    startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: This should get you started: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/examples/

Comment: I have same problem in iphone.

Comment: Has this anything at all to do with the file format "PDF" in particular? It seems only (very) tangentially related to me.

Comment: @RanjanSahu, then you should post another question about it (after doing some research, of course), as the code will not be the same ...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at *user2459928's* the answer here: [Android Launch a Google Drive application from another application not uploaded file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964218/android-launch-a-google-drive-application-from-another-application-not-uploaded)

Additionally, I would highly suggest wrapping the startActivity() in a try catch block just in case the user does not have the app that you are trying to launch installed on their device.

```
Uri pdfUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/file"));

try {
    Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from((Activity) context)
                .setText("Share PDF file")
                .setType("application/pdf")
                .setStream(pdfUri)
                .getIntent()
                .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs");
    context.startActivity(shareIntent);
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    // show a Toast or messag saying "activity not found" or "application not installed on this device"
}
```