# How to upload a pdf file to google drive in android application

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I m trying to upload new pdf file to google drive in android application. but it throws null exception. it  only upload image format. so please give any suggestion how to upload pdf file.

```
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, 
                                final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                try {
                    mBitmapToSave = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                            getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), filenameSP, 3000).show();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mBitmapToSave = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                        getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
```

Here I am passing my pdf file path its throw `nullPointerException`.

Comment: You may look at this link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964218/android-launch-a-google-drive-application-from-another-application-not-uploaded][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964218/android-launch-a-google-drive-application-from-another-application-not-uploaded

Comment: Same thing i have done but its not working...

Comment: No stack trace and corresponding line numbered code?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the following links

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads

https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/