# How to make android app choose default pdf file viewer choose as Drive?

Tags: android

Is there a way to open a pdf (stored on drive) to open in Google Drive PDF Viewer in Android. While I am using ACTION_VIEW, it shows open with options like drive and browser. Is there a way that by default it opens in Drive. It's okay even if it switches to drive by default.

My Code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pdf_link));
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: You can target the intent directly https://stackoverflow.com/a/16986759/529282 Note that it's from seven years ago, the code might need some adjustment. Feel free to answer your own question if you managed to update it for current Android

Comment: The user might not have that PDF viewer. And, the user might want to use a different PDF viewer.

Comment: @CommonsWare it's okay. My target users are supposed to have Drive. And I can handle if drive doesn't exist with a check condition, and in that case, opening it in the way I am doing right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer. Following code does select Google Drive by default.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pdf_url));
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs");
startActivity(intent);
```

But this still lists all google accounts and asks one to open with. How can we proceed with default google account to open the pdf in drive?